# Perforce on Cygwin Prompts for a visible password

Tags: command-line, passwords, cygwin, perforce

When I run the perforce login command in a cygwin shell running inside a mintty terminal emulator, the password prompted by perforce is *visible*--as I type the characters that make up my password, the characters get echoed right back to the password prompt.

`$ p4 login
Enter password: abc123`

I'm not sure which actor here is in charge of displaying and reading the password prompt: perforce? cygwin? or mintty?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use the Cygwin build (discontinued from May 1, 2013):

http://www.perforce.com/downloads/perforce/r11.1/bin.cygwinx86/p4.exe